# How do I remove .html from my website pages?

Tags: html, url

My HTML pages (e.g. cv.html) carry the file extension to the URL when loaded.

So I have www.mysite.com/cv.html

and I want:

www.mysite.com/cv

How do I do this??

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This has many, many answers even when Googling `How do I remove .html from my website pages?`. Always remember to do that first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need URL rewriting. You need to go to your .htaccess file and write something like this.

`RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule    ^cv?$    cv.html    [NC,L]`

If your user types in `www.mysite.com/cv`, it will show up contents of `www.mysite.com/cv.html`

Last parts are flags. `NC (case insensitive)`.`L(last - stop processing rules)`